auto-completion and error detection feature in Python file of ROS2 Package in Docker
I setup ROS2 with VSCode and Docker using https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/Setup-ROS-2-with-VSCode-and-Docker-Container.html
The following is the structure of the folders and files in VS Code: https://i.sstatic.net/xTprAgiI.png
There are yellow squiggly lines under "rclpy" and "rclpy.node" in the "simple_publisher.py" file, this is the cause for the yellow warnings in the previous image: https://i.sstatic.net/8M1tUStT.png
I have also pasted the code in the "simple_publisher.py" file below:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

class SimplePublisher(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

Also the auto-completion and the error detection features for the Python code does not work all the time.
An example of the auto-completion feature not working, is that there are no suggestions coming up when typing:
def __init_

As seen in https://i.sstatic.net/JfzpQoX2.png
However, sometimes there are suggestions such as:
Suggestions while typing
An example of the error detection feature not working is that there is no red squiggly line after typing:
def __init__(sef): 

As seen in no error detection
The following extensions are installed in VS code:

"Pylance"
"Python"
"Python Debugger"
"Python Environment Manager"
"Python Extension Pack"
“Remote – SSH”
“Remote – SSH: Edit Configuration Files”
“Remote – Tunnels”
“Remote Development”
“WSL”
“IntelliCode”
“IntelliCode API Usage Examples”

Is there a way to get rid of the yellow squiggly lines under "rclpy" and "rclpy.node" above. Also is there a way to get the auto-completion and error detection features to work all the time?

In order for pylance Intellisense to work in a docker environment, we usually also need to install the remote-ssh extension.
Make sure that the SSH service is running in your Docker container and that you can connect to the container via SSH. You must configure the SSH service for the container and set the corresponding username and password or SSH key.
After connecting to the container, you could select python interpreter by using shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and typing "Python: Select Interpreter".

I found out that auto-completion of some python commands work. I have included an example of this in the edited question above.
I read https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh however I am still not sure on the way to ensure the SSH service is running in the Docker container, connecting to the container using SSH and configuring the SSH service of the container then setting a username and password or SSH key.
I would now also like to target the yellow squiggly lines under “rclpy” and “rclpy.node”. I edited my question above to reflect the changes relating to the these yellow lines

Also I have mentioned other extensions that I installed including the " Remote – SSH", in the edited question above

You could configure your .devcontainer/devcontainer.json for remoting if needed. And sometimes, rebuilding the Intellisense database can help. Open your VSCode Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and select Python: Restart Language Server.

Thank you for your response. Could you direct me to some useful resources for beginners, on the way to configure the devcontainer.json file?

Hello, you can refer to the official document or GitHub for more examples and templates.
